# differences between this month sum and before [mysql]

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables the first one is **head_order** with values as it shown

```
id_order    name    date
1           john    2018-05-11
2           andre   2018-05-11
3           johan   2018-06-11
4           louis   2018-06-11
5           brock   2018-07-11
6           peter   2018-07-11
```

and 2nd table is **det_order**

```
id_det id_head    items    g_total
1      1          5        100.000
2      2          11       75.000
3      3          7        80.000
4      4          8        80.500
5      5          4        220.000
6      6          6        226.000
```

based on that 2 table i made a report that showed the count of items bought and sum of g_total per month and i want to add another field that show the difference of sum of g_total this month with sum of g_total last month , this is my mySQL query

```
SELECT 
MONTH(a.date) as mth ,
count(a.name) as cnt ,
sum(b.g_total) as sm ,
sum(b.g_total) - 
(SELECT sum(x.g_total) FROM head_order y LEFT JOIN det_order x on y.id_order=x.id_head 
WHERE MONTH(y.date) < MONTH(a.date) GROUP BY MONTH(y.date) limit 1 ) as cs, 
(SELECT sum(x.g_total) FROM head_order y LEFT JOIN det_order x n y.id_order=x.id_head 
WHERE MONTH(y.date) < MONTH(a.date) GROUP BY MONTH(y.date)  limit 1 ) as pctg 
FROM head_order a LEFT JOIN det_order b on .id_order=b.id_head 
GROUP BY YEAR(a.date), MONTH(a.date)
```

the results come out like these

```
mth  cnt  sm       cs      pctg 
5    2    175.000  null    null
6    2    160.500  -14.500 175.000
7    2    446.000  271.000 175.000
```

when it should come out like these

```
mth  cnt  sm       cs      pctg 
5    2    175.000  null    null
6    2    160.500  -14.500 175.000
7    2    446.000  285.500 160.500
```

where's wrong with my mySQL query though ?

Comment: You could fix the syntax errors in your code (where do you get y.id_order from it doesn't exist in the data)- but I suspect you need an order by desc clause before limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An order by desc before the limit clause would do it

```
SELECT 
MONTH(a.date) as mth ,
count(a.name) as cnt ,
sum(b.g_total) as sm ,
sum(b.g_total) - 
(SELECT sum(x.g_total) FROM head_order y LEFT JOIN det_order x on y.id=x.id_head 
WHERE MONTH(y.date) < MONTH(a.date) GROUP BY MONTH(y.date) order by month(y.date) desc limit 1 ) as cs, 
(SELECT sum(x.g_total) FROM head_order y LEFT JOIN det_order x on y.id=x.id_head 
WHERE MONTH(y.date) < MONTH(a.date) GROUP BY MONTH(y.date) order by month(y.date) desc limit 1 ) as pctg 
FROM head_order a 
LEFT JOIN det_order b on a.id=b.id_head 
GROUP BY YEAR(a.date), MONTH(a.date);

+------+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| mth  | cnt | sm      | cs      | pctg    |
+------+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|    5 |   2 | 175.000 |    NULL |    NULL |
|    6 |   2 | 160.500 | -14.500 | 175.000 |
|    7 |   2 | 446.000 | 285.500 | 160.500 |
+------+-----+---------+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: ahh spot on !! scratching my head for almost 2 hours by this little detail , many thanks